# How do I avoid the mat-options to render over a fixed mat-toolbar header when scrolling?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to implement a layout where I have a toolbar/header that I want to be fixed at the top of all components. And all the other components (including the router-outlet) to render under that toolbar/header.

But if I use a mat-autocomplete, open the options, don't select any option and scroll the page to the bottom the mat-autocomplete options are rendered over the header, not under it like all the other content.

[MatOptions rendered over the MatToolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKjhB.png)

I tried setting the z-index of the toolbar to 2000, because the z-index of the autocomplete options are 1000. But I'm still getting the options rendered over the header and not under it.

The problem can be reproduced here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-zvys8y?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by moving the `mat-header` outside of the `mat-sidenav-container`

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="position-fixed text-start">
 ...
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
 ...
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-jokcqx?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html

[image]